# How to use column name as part of a LIKE statement in a WHERE clause of a JOIN

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-like

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [INVENTTRANS]
ON #TEMP.VOUCHERPHYSICAL=[INVENTTRANS].VOUCHERPHYSICAL
WHERE [INVENTTRANS].ITEMID = #Temp.INVENTDIMID
```

This provides me nearly the result I am looking for. About 1/4th of the desired results are eliminated because `INVENTDIMID` has a suffix appended to it in certain cases.

What is the proper syntax to succeed in a like clause similar to this intent.

```
WHERE '[INVENTTRANS].ITEMID%' like #Temp.INVENTDIMID
```

Alternatively, if there is no short hand way to do this, what is the most effective long handed way about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand the question but it appears you want to apply a predicate to a like statement that compares something else that is fixed and not in text you supply.

I always do something like this:

```
Where (ColumnName) like '%' + (OtherColumnName) + '%'
```

This is basically applying a wildcard around either side of the column you are trying to relate to. It will work for variables or columns.

UPDATE 5-21-13

Simple example of two table variables that self populate and work with wild card matcing on the second table variable.  Code will run as is on SQL 2008 or higher in SQL Management Studio:

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

declare @Match table ( Description varchar(4));

insert into @Match values ('B'), ('S'),('e')

Select top 100
    p.*
,   m.Description as 'MatchedOn'
from @Person p, @Match m
where p.person like '%' + m.Description + '%'
```

Comment: This is close to my intent. I had hoped to apply the wildcard to what was inside the column.

300794 matches on 300794
344411 matches on 34441125

Comment: This should work then, take a look at updated example for further review.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I had the order of operations reversed and was looking for instances of the longer result in the shorter. It appears I still have further issues, but you have helped me eliminate one option.

Thanks.