# Inner Join with LIKE, what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables

```
Table 'prd_help_zusatz'
ID   Title   ART
1    Text 1  material
2    Text 2  material
3    Text 3  farbe

Table 'prd_produkt'
ID   PRD_material ...
1    [1][2]
2    [2]
```

The `PRD_material` from `prd_produkt` are IDs from the `prd_help_zusatz` in `[]` as many as materials are chosen. Now I would like to give out all the possible values from `prd_help_zusatz` which are materials that are used by `prd_produkt`.

My Select-Code

```
SELECT h.ID 
FROM prd_help_zusatz as h, prd_produkt as p 
WHERE h.ART = 'material' 
  AND p.PRDART = 'uhr' 
  AND h.ID LIKE p.PRD_material 
GROUP BY h.Titel_d
```

The Problem is, that on `PRD_material` the values are not equal. How can I select this? .. `h.ID LIKE '['p.PRD_material']'` doesn't work.

Comment: What's wrong?  Your data structure.  You should *not* store lists of ids in a string.  You should have a proper junction table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   prd_help_zusatz h
JOIN   prd_produkt p 
  ON   p.PRD_material LIKE CONCAT('%', h.ID, '%') AND
       p.PRDART = 'uhr'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/727f7/2)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `%` operator where you wish to be looking for matches. If you want to compare a column on a column you would put this on both sides. If you wish to compare the left hand side only, you would place it there. I suggest looking at this thread for a bit more insight: [How to use column name as part of a LIKE statement in a WHERE clause of a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594460/how-to-use-column-name-as-part-of-a-like-statement-in-a-where-clause-of-a-join)

So:

```
SELECT h.ID 
FROM      prd_help_zusatz as h, 
          prd_produkt as p 
WHERE     h.ART = 'material' 
          AND p.PRDART = 'uhr' 
          AND h.ID LIKE '%' + p.PRD_material + '%'
GROUP BY  h.Titel_d
```

Comment: Would need to be  `p.PRD_material like concat('%[', h.ID,']%')` based on the sample data and IIRC `+` does not work for string concatenation in MySQL

Comment: thanks for the info, but this '%'+p.PRD_material+'%' gives me an sql error. It seems this combination '%'+.. is wrong