# Replace strings from a table to another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables in SQL-Server:

1st table is Product

```
ID       NameEnglish          NameFrench 
1        Box of Banana          NA
2        Product apple          NA
3        Pallet of Bread        NA
```

2nd table Translation

```
NameEnglish       NameFrench 
Banana            Banane
apple             Pomme
Bread             Pain
```

I want to update the 1st table with the following in the column (Namefrench) based on my table Translation

```
ID       NameEnglish             NameFrench 
1        Box of Banana          Box of Banane 
2        Product apple          Product Pomme
3        Pallet of Bread        Pallet of Pain
```

How I can Replace and Update my column NameFrench?

Comment: can you shared your sql?

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Comment: hint : use `JOIN`, `LIKE`, `REPLACE()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE P 
    SET P.NameFrench= REPLACE(P.NameEnglish,T.NameEnglish,T.NameFrench)
FROM Product P 
    INNER JOIN Translation T ON P.NameEnglish LIKE '%' + T.NameEnglish + '%'
```

Here it is joined on Product NameEnglish which contains Translation NameEnglish.
Also used replace Translation NameEnglish with NameFrench in Product NameEnglish column.

Reference:

[REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[How to use column name as part of a LIKE statement in a WHERE clause of a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594460/how-to-use-column-name-as-part-of-a-like-statement-in-a-where-clause-of-a-join)

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
UPDATE t1 SET namefrench = REPLACE(t1.nameenglish, RIGHT(RTRIM(t1.NameEnglish), LEN(t2.NameEnglish)), t2.NameFrench) 
        FROM table1 t1 
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 
        ON RIGHT(RTRIM(t1.NameEnglish), LEN(t2.NameEnglish)) = t2.NameEnglish
```